# Oracle CONSTRAINT to ensure seconds are zero

Tags: oracle, date, constraints

Is there a way to create a CONSTRAINT on a date column that will check if the seconds is a value other then 0

I only want to allow values in this format MMDDYYYY HH24:MI

I know the following will be a violation if hours, minutes or seconds are values other than zero.

CONSTRAINT dt_chk check (dt=trunc(dt,'dd'))

Answer (score 5):

Just truncate to minutes instead of days:

```
CONSTRAINT dt_chk check (dt=trunc(dt,'MI'))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e7aaf4dc53013abdb76fb2b580492de)

Read more in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html#GUID-BC82227A-2698-4EC8-8C1A-ABECC64B0E79).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this might be using a constraint this way:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ;

Session altered.

SQL> create table test.test_chk ( c1 date );

Table created.

SQL> alter table test.test_chk add constraint check_second check ( extract(second from cast(c1 as timestamp)) = 0 );

Table altered.

SQL>  insert into test.test_chk values ( '01.01.2020 13:15:22' ) ;
 insert into test.test_chk values ( '01.01.2020 13:15:22' )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (TEST.CHECK_SECOND) violated


SQL> insert into test.test_chk values ( '01.01.2020 13:15:00' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

Comment: If `extract` worked on `date` data type directly, this would be a good approach. Unfortunately (and for no reason I can understand), it doesn't - so this approach also requires a cast to timestamp. Which already makes it a poorer approach than the one already posted by Alex Poole before you posted yours. Note also that `extract` returns `number` - don't compare to the string `'00'`, you should compare to the number `0` instead. All in all, not a useful Answer.

Comment: Thanks all for your input.

Comment: @mathguy , you were right regarding the number output of the extract function. I corrected the answer. But saying not a useful answer I think it is a bit harsh and not polite at all. For sure Alex Poole answer is better, but I was trying to provide a second alternative. You might have said that is not as good as his, but not a useful answer is not polite and the purpose of this site is precisely to share solutions across the community. some will be better than others, some won't work, but saying not useful is against what I think this site is about